# Can I setup a webserver on a private network?

Tags: networking, router, dns, webserver

I am trying to setup a webserver on our company's private network. I have the domain name `www.myurlexample.com` which needs to resolve to a server here on my network. But I'm struggling to figure it out...

My network has a DC handling DNS at 192.168.1.24.

My IIS server is at 192.168.1.27.

I have an adtran router which has an ACL and NAT statements that go from public to private for the DC and the IIS server.

On the DC in DNS, I have setup a Forward Lookup Zone called `myurlexample.com`. I have the following entries:

```
(same as parent folder) Name Server ns1.myurlexample.com.
(same as parent folder) Name Server servername.domainname.local.
(same as parent folder) Start of Authority servername.domainname.local, hostmaster.domainname.local.
ns1 Host (A) 192.168.1.24
ns2 Host (A) 192.168.1.27
www Host (A) 192.168.1.27
```

On my domain registrar, I have pointed the www.myurlexample.com nameservers to `ns1.myurlexample.com` (public IP address of DNS server) and `ns2.myurlexample.com` (public IP address of IIS server).

When I visit `www.myurlexample.com` from inside my network everything works as expected. When I visit `www.myurlexample.com` from outside my network, I get "This webpage is not available."

I'm sure I'm just missing something, but I'm not sure what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you route port 80 to the internal server?

Comment: Yes, and I can get to the server using the external IP but just not with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your delegation sounds incorrect. These addresses should point to DNS servers only, not directly to the IIS server. If you only have the one DNS server, leave the second entry blank. AS @Hennes mentioned, the DNS server needs to return a public IP address. I'm guessing at the moment it's returning an internal IP address, which would be why it's failing. If you have a public IP for the webserver (which sounds a little unusual), then this is the address the DNS server should return.

Possibly a better configuration may be to use an external DNS service for the domain delegation, and then keep your internal DNS server pointing the domain to the private internal IP address.